# svn pre-commit hook for validating files to be checked in

Tags: svn-hooks

i have to write a pre commit hook that will not allow developers to commit files having a particular string.can this be done?
also whenever files are checked in by developers from their workstation are they temporarily saved anywhere on the svn server??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. You can look at SVN transaction contents before commiting it with `svnlook` command.

A Python example doing something similiar to your question (rejecting C++ files with tabs in them) can be found here: http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook